# Use a Google Form to update an existing Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Is there a way to update an existing sheet in a Google spreadsheet using a Google form? I only see how to update to a new tab (sheet) on an existing spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert or link a form to a spreadsheet, a new sheet is always created. This makes sense because the data is transmitted in a specific way: column A is Timestamp, etc. The algorithm isn't meant to work around some pre-existing data in the sheet, so it pulls out a clean sheet to work with.

But you can achieve the desired effect by copying the contents of your existing sheet to the Form Responses sheet after it's created, and then deleting the original.